# How can i add measure tool in openlayers3?

Tags: widget, distance, openlayers-3, area, measure

I have developed an one application using openlayers3. Now, i want to add measurement tool in that. Does anybody know the solution?
i have tried some examples. but they are in openlayers6.

Since the support has been stopped for ol3.i couldn't get any solution

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/measure.html